# Gstreamer sync multiple videos from multiple sources

Tags: video, gstreamer, mp4

I have what is essentially a homebuilt video conferencing system using Raspberry Pis. It's a system that's been in use for the last couple years and for the most part, things are working fine.

One of the requirements is to save a copy of the audio and video for later playback. Using Gstreamer, the Pi captures H264 video and ac3 audio, then sends to the recording server over rtp. Below is the current pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin \
    v4l2src do-timestamp=true device=/dev/video0 ! \
            queue ! \
            video/x-h264,width=1024,height=768,framerate=24/1,stream-format=byte-stream ! \
            rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 ! \
            rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 \
            rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! multiudpsink clients=$Server:$RtspVideoPort,$Server:$ForwardVideoPort,$Server:$RecordVideoPort \
            rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=$Server port=$RtcpVideoPort sync=false async=false \
    alsasrc do-timestamp=true ! \
            queue ! \
            avenc_ac3_fixed ! \
            rtpac3pay pt=97 ! \
            rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1 \
            rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ! multiudpsink clients=$Server:$RtspAudioPort,$Server:$ForwardAudioPort,$Server:$RecordAudioPort \
            rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! udpsink host=$Server port=$RtcpAudioPort sync=false async=false \
    >> "logs/source_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).log"  2>&1 &
```

And since it's a video conferencing system (which in this case only involves two participants), there are two Pis running this pipeline.

On the server side, I have the following two pipelines for each of the conference participants:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e udpsrc port=videorecordport1
        ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264 
        ! rtph264depay 
        ! video/x-h264,framerate=24/1 
        ! mpegtsmux 
        ! filesink location="recordedvideo1.mp4"
```

and

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e udpsrc port=audiorecordport1
        ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=44100, encoding-name=AC3 
        ! rtpac3depay 
        ! ac3parse 
        ! filesink location="recordedaudio1.ac3"
```

The intention is that these conferences last a certain amount of time. After they finish, the server will combine the two video files and two audio files. This is done with the following...

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="recordedvideo1.mp4" 
        ! tsdemux 
        ! decodebin 
        ! queue 
        ! videomixer name=mix sink_0::xpos=0 sink_1::xpos=1024
        ! x264enc 
        ! mpegtsmux name=mux
        ! filesink location="finalvideo.mp4" filesrc location="recordedvideo2.mp4" 
        ! tsdemux 
        ! decodebin 
        ! queue 
        ! mix. filesrc location="recordedaudio1.ac3"
        ! ac3parse 
        ! a52dec
        ! queue
        ! audiomixer name=amix
        ! audioconvert
        ! avenc_ac3_fixed
        ! mux. filesrc location="recordedaudio2.ac3"
        ! ac3parse
        ! a52dec
        ! queue
        ! amix.
```

The reason for saving separate files for later muxing is that we have enough video conversations going on at the same time that the server would be swamped. Better to mux them together at times where that's not the case.

So I've read a bit on how this all works, but I'm still not sure if my implementation is correct. Specifically, syncing these all together. If my understanding is correct, the Pis will utilize their system clock for reference when generating timestamps for the outgoing a/v streams. I believe that's the need for do-timestamp. And if both Pis have the same clock, then all four streams should just "match up" when I'm muxing.

Here's my dilemma. This works fine most of the time. However, we are occasionally having some glitches. You can see sync issues sometimes when watching the muxed video. And quite often you can see the two source videos are almost exactly the same length, but the final video is 10 seconds shorter. And in some cases we've had final video multiple minutes shorter.

My initial research on this was directed more at making sure the Pis had matching clocks. We have two AD controllers, which by default is apparently where the Pis were getting time. One of them was randomly going up to 20 or so minutes of drift, and that could happen a few times a day. Needless to say, that's not a great thing.

My fix was to change the Pis to ignore getting time from our internal network and instead rely on the default ntp config. I think that has helped a lot, but I still notice we have some muxed videos with 10 or so second differences that aren't expected.

I guess what I want to know is a sanity check as to whether I'm doing this correctly, or does it just have the appearance of working correctly most of the time. That would help before I put more effort into proving we still have clock sync issues on our Pis.

The biggest thing that I'm wondering is whether timestamps are working the way I think.

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm saving the incoming streams to files?

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm muxing those files?

The pipelines on the server that save the streams to files are all separate. Should those all be combined into one gstreamer process? I can't think that would help because that would be more for if the server was adding timestamps wouldn't it?

Per suggestion, I have attempted to use rtpbin on the receiving end. Not really having much success. That might have been why I wasn't using it in the first place. For instance, this works...

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 
    ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000, payload=96, encoding-name=H264 
    ! rtph264depay 
    ! video/x-h264,framerate=24/1 
    ! decodebin 
    ! autovideosink
```

But this does not:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin udpsrc port=5000 
    ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000, payload=96, encoding-name=H264 
    ! rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin. 
    ! rtph264depay 
    ! video/x-h264,framerate=24/1 
    ! decodebin 
    ! autovideosink
```

Error is "Internal data flow error", followed by "streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated". The rtpbin pipeline was based on the example in the gstreamer docs, but modified for my situation. And I removed all the rtcp stuff to simplify it. I've tried a number of variations on this pipeline with no luck. This was tested on the windows build of Gstreamer 1.8.2

Another edit... kind of weird, but rtpbin apparently requires media=video in the caps, whereas not using rtpbin does not. Guess I have it working now.

Comment: 1. mpegtsmux does not create .mp4 files. This is misleading. 2. Saving raw AC3 audio discards any timestamp information that is received from RTP. 3. I don't see any RTP bin on the receivers - seems like RTCP is not even considered which has additional sync information between the tracks.

Comment: On your first point, what file does it create? I will take a look at using rtp bin.

Comment: I guess it's supposed to be a .mts file? Not sure where I got mp4. Must have been some example I was basing it off of that was wrong.

Comment: Usually .ts.. you can save it as MP4 if you want if you change muxers.

Comment: I guess my video players were smart enough to know it really wasn't an mp4 file since it played fine. It might have been that I was using the correct muxer a long time ago, changed it, and didn't think about looking at the file extension.